# Delete child element of a div onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, removechild

**what I have**

I have a parent div of class = "alphabets" and have child div's all with same class = "word"

```
<div class="alphabets">
  <div class="word"> abc </div>
  <div class="word"> def </div>
  <div class="word"> ghi </div>
  <div class="word"> jkl </div>
  <div class="word"> mno </div>
</div>
```

**what I need**
when I click on 'abc' it should get deleted, if clicked on 'jkl' it should be deleted, i.e on which text (word) I click it should get deleted.

Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the event.target property to determine which child element was clicked on. Once you know which element was clicked, you can use the remove() method

```js
const alphabets = document.querySelector('.alphabets');

alphabets.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('word')) {
    event.target.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="alphabets">
  <div class="word"> abc </div>
  <div class="word"> def </div>
  <div class="word"> ghi </div>
  <div class="word"> jkl </div>
  <div class="word"> mno </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a jQuery library which provides an easy way for working with the DOM.

```js
$('.word').click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alphabets">
  <div class="word"> abc </div>
  <div class="word"> def </div>
  <div class="word"> ghi </div>
  <div class="word"> jkl </div>
  <div class="word"> mno </div>
</div>
```